# Wordpress User Meta retrieving advance data for meta_key

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a custom profile form for one of my websites based on Wordpress. I am using add more button for a particular field since I do not know how many inputs may the user like to enter for it.

I am inserting the data into wp_usermeta;  I have no issues while inserting the data however while retrieving I can’t get the count of the meta_key since the meta key stored are as ts_date_1 ts_date_2 etc

Thanks for your time.

HTML:

```
<tr><td><input type='text' name='ts_date[]' id='ts_date_1' /></td></tr>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function addanotherts() {
   var root=document.getElementById('timesheettable');
   var divs=root.getElementsByTagName('tr');
   var clone=divs[divs.length-1].cloneNode(true);
   root.appendChild(clone);
   var root=document.getElementById('timesheettable');
   var divs=root.getElementsByTagName('tr');
   var aaa = divs.length-1;
   var abc = divs[divs.length-1];

   abc1 = abc.getElementsByTagName("input");
   abc1[0].setAttribute("id",'ts_date_'+aaa);
   abc1[0].value = '';

   abc2 = abc.getElementsByTagName("select");
   abc2[0].setAttribute("id",'ts_comments_'+aaa);
   abc2[0].value = '';

  }
  </script>
```

PHP:
For inserting into DB

```
$ts_date = $_POST['ts_date'];
for($ii = 0 ; $ii < count($ts_date) ; $ii++) {
if(!empty ($ts_date[$ii])){
    update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'ts_date_'.$ii, esc_attr( $ts_date[$ii] ) );
}
}
```

For Retriving from DB **

- (note: Note in the following code $ii < 10; 10 is an assumed number
  but not the actual count. )

**

```
<?php
 for($ii = 0; $ii < 10; $ii++){
?>
<tr>
    <td><input type='text' name='ts_date_<?php echo $ii ?>' value="<?php echo esc_attr(  get_the_author_meta( 'ts_date_'.$ii, $user->ID ) );?>"  /></td>
</tr>
<?php
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
  $ii = 0;
  while($meta_field = get_the_author_meta( 'ts_date_'.$ii, $user->ID )) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><input type='text' name='ts_date_<?php echo $ii ?>' value="<?php echo esc_attr( $meta_field );?>"  /></td>
</tr>
<?php
 $ii++;
 }
?>
```

This will loop until $meta_field is an empty string. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta.